# MySQL userscore per round

Tags: mysql

Currently I'm struggling with a MySQL query. I want to calculate the score for a user per round. I'm trying to get the user that has the best score for a certain round.

My current result:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(result_points), round_id 
FROM result 
GROUP by user_id, round_id 
ORDER by round_id ASC, MAX(result_points) DESC
```

Query result:

[image: Query result]

Seems to be fine, thing is: I only need the user with the highest score per round.
Like this:

[image: preferred score]

Do you have any idea how to accomplish this with the given query?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the query that you have as a subquery along with the MAX function on the total points per round that you are getting from your query.

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(roundResults.points) as points, round_id 
FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(result_points) as points, round_id 
    FROM result 
    GROUP by user_id, round_id
    ORDER by round_id, points DESC) AS roundResults
GROUP by round_id
```

See the [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/785d8/54).

Note: ORDER BY points DESC preserves the user_id placement.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(result_points), round_id 
FROM result 
GROUP by user_id, round_id 
ORDER by round_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using a SUM() because there can be diferent result_points for the same user_id and round_id. If that's not the case, you could try:

```
SELECT result.user_id, result.result_points, result.round_id 
FROM result 
  JOIN (
    SELECT b.round_id, MAX(b.result_points) AS max_result_points
    FROM result b
    GROUP BY b.round_id
  ) a ON result.round_id = a.round_id AND result.result_points = a.max_result_points
ORDER BY result.round_id
```